# Waiting for other software manager to quit

Tags: package-management, software-center

I'm unable to install any of the programs from Ubuntu Software Center. It constantly stays at 0 % with the following message: 'Waiting for other software manager to quit.' 
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have synaptic or the ubuntu software center open?Have a look under processes.

To see running processes goto System-->Administration-->System Monitor

[image]

Search for the processes that says apt-get or synaptic.If you find any process,select the process and click End Process.

If no process were running but still if you cant install any packages then type the following in terminal..

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

This will remove the lock,now you can install packages..

Also See this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9137287&postcount=2)

Comment: Thank you for help! There were no apt-get or synaptic processes. Were exactly I need to type in: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock ?

Comment: Yes type that, it removes any lock on dpkg that you might have.

Comment: Were do I type it in?

Comment: Type that in terminal.To open terminal Goto Applications-->Accessories-->Terminal

Comment: After I pasted sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
in the terminal it required my password. I keep writing it in but the system wont accept it.

Comment: You should enter your sudo password which is your system password.

Comment: Yes, password was accepted finally. Now I have this message: 2010-11-19 15:17:58 (446 KB/s) - `./adobe-flashplugin_10.1.102.64.orig.tar.gz' saved [4970105/4970105]

Download done.
Flash Plugin installed.

Setting up xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.9.0-1ubuntu2.2) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Although it says that now I have adobe-flashplugin, I'm still not able to watch online videos nor listen to mp3 files. Besides, I still have 16 updates that have not been made, can somehow do them one by one in the Terminal, or should I do sth else?

Comment: Oh are you able to install the packages now?Type  **sudo apt-get update** in terminal and then reinstall it again.

Comment: Wonderful! It worked. Thank you so much for your help. Updates were finished and now I'm able to watch all my online video/music files.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have a terminal process or synaptic currently "in charge" of installing software.  Ubuntu stops new programs that are in charge of installing/removing/updating software from starting when there is an existing application/process that has the same function.  You probably just need to wait for an application you were previously using to close/relinquish software changing rights and/or close that process if you have not already done so.

Comment: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

Comment: I can't make any updates as well. How do I run 'sudo dpkg' manually?